# Correct translation for "smoke" that also means "cigarette"

Tags: word-choice, translation, conversation, informal

In English, we can use the term "smoke" as a noun to refer to a cigarette. For example:

> I'd like to have a smoke.
>
> *(meaning, "I'd like to smoke a cigarette.")*

Google Translate gives me **담배** as the translation for cigarette ([see here](https://translate.google.com/?client=opera&oe=UTF-8&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&client=tw-ob#en/ko/cigarette)).

As for "smoke", as used in the example above, Google Translate gave me **연기** which is defined there as "smoke, performance, fume, postponement, extension, deferment" ([see here](https://translate.google.com/?client=opera&oe=UTF-8&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&client=tw-ob#en/ko/smoke))... which made me confused, so I am guessing that this is not the correct term.

I'm wondering if there exists a Korean term equivalent to "smoke" the way it is used in the sentence above. Please let me know if there is. Thank you.

Comment: No, there isn't one. The closest to that expression you can get is probably by omitting the object - so saying "한 대만 펴도 될까요?".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most commonly used expression for the verb "to smoke (a cigarette)" is (담배를) 피(우)다. Sometimes 담배를 태우다 is used too. In literary language, it appears in the form of 흡연하다. Also, very informally, 담배를 빨다 is used.

The difference between 피다 and 피우다 in this context is minor, although 담배를 피다 is not considered the standard.

As a side note, 연기 is the noun "smoke" as in the smoke that comes out of a chimney. Also, the counting word for 담배 is 개비(each), 갑(pack), or 대(session).